# How filter words with first char in capital with RegEx?

Tags: php, regex, string

i was trying to filter words with the first char in capital and replace with '*'. (I'm on php)

This is an example input:

> " foo Foo FOO "

The correct output:

> "foo *** *** ".

This is my code:

```
$pattern = " THIS IS WHAT I NEED! ";
$replaceWith = "*";
$result = preg_replace($pattern, $replaceWith, " foo Foo FOO ");
```

I hope you can help me, i'm new on regex and i need a quick solution!

UPDATED:

> Expression like this:
>
> (?:^|(?<=\s))[A-Z]\w*\b

Does not consider the accent (used in spanish language). "Canción" (song) is and example. See this other example:
https://regex101.com/r/iZ6oY7/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[A-Z][^\s]+
```

view demo:

[regexr.com](http://regexr.com/3ajir)

Answer (score 2):

```
(?:^|(?<=\s))[A-Z]\w*\b
```

Try this.Replace by `*`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/iS6jF6/26

Comment: Works, but, yo know how to consider the accent (used in spanish language). Like "Canción" (song), or "Avión" (airplane).

See how to this regex only find the first letter only!
https://regex101.com/r/iZ6oY7/2

Answer (score 1):

You can use word boundaries here and then match `[A-Z]` to make sure word start with an uppercase letter:

```
$s = ' foo Foo FOO ';
echo preg_replace('/\b[A-Z]\w*\b/', '*', $s);
//=> foo * *
```

To make it **unicode compliant** use:

```
echo preg_replace('/\b\p{Lu}\w*\b/', '*', $s);
//=> foo * *
```